# caret jumping out of line in contentedetible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that adds HTML to a `div` on keypress which works well. However when I'm adding an `ol` element or `ul` and adding the `div` to `contenteditable` the `div` added at the start of `contenteditable` gets out of the `ol``ul`. Here's my code:

```
divEditor.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        var current = $("#divEditor").html();
        $("#divEditor").html([current.slice(0), '<span id="cc">text</span>', current.slice(0)].join(''));
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding the `div` as a direct child to an `ol` or `ul`? [`ol`/`ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) can contain `li`s only, a `div`would be parsed outside of a list.

Comment: yes..theres no way just to add the to inline of li?

Comment: No, there isn't. Browsers will fix an invalid HTML automatically, if you're trying to force a div to appear directly in a list. You've to wrap the div within a `li`. Btw. There's no `div` in the posted code?

Comment: so how i can detect the last elemt(li or whatever) andd add the div to him as li?

Comment: i have tried just to add &nbsp;instead if the div and its still jumping out of the ol,any ideas?

Comment: `nbsp;` is not a `li` element, that's _the only_ permitted content within lists. You'd probably get more specific answer(s), if you created and saved a full example of your current code at http://jsfiddle.net